# Mercurial ошибка 255 при попытке сделать коммит

Tags: mercurial, tortoise-hg

При работе с репозиторием Mercurial появилась ошибка при попытке сделать коммит. Такая ошибка уже появлялась, решал я её костыльно: загружал репозиторий на сервер, создавал на компьютере заново и выгружал на компьютер с сервера. После этого всё работало, но теперь ошибка проявилась опять. Кто-нибудь знает, как решить?
[image: Скрин из Tortiose]

[image: Скрин из командной строки]

Comment: Возможно, вы сначала пробовали выполнить одну команду mercurial, потом не дождавшись ее окончания запустили другую команду.

Comment: Не нужно одновременно больше 1 операции выполнять над репозиторием.

Comment: Вроде бы несколько операций одновременно не выполнял

Comment: посмотри наличие файлов `.hg/wlock` и `.hg/store/lock` и удали

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё работает

Comment: ага, не за что. у меня эта ошибка часто появлялась из-за того что ide не очень удачно пыталась что-то как-то синхронизировать с репозиторием mercurial. убрал из ide hg-плагин и теперь всё ровно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая ошибка может возникнуть, если пытаться параллельно выполнять несколько команд mercurial. Или предыдущая команда была прервана с ошибкой, из-за чего блокировка с рабочей директории не была снята. Блокировка также может висеть, если несколько человек параллельно работают с репозиторием mercurial, расположенным в общей папке в локальной сети (так не нужно делать, лучше поднять вебсервер mercurial).

Для снятия блокировки удалите файл `.hg/store/lock` или `.hg/wlock` в рабочей папке.

Comment: Заработало, спасибо. У меня как раз лежит в общей папке

Comment: @Jaxx34, ну значит мой внутренний телепат сегодня не в отпуске)